# android regex odd behavior

Tags: java, android, regex

What is the error with the following regular expression? It is working fine in Java whereas android throws "Pattern Syntax Exception".

```
         "((?<==)+(\"[^\"]+\"|[^,=+<>#;\r\n]+))"
```

Comment: i think you need to escape double times.

Comment: you have to remove the `+` after lookbehind.

Comment: @AvinashRaj,I don't think this way you can solve problem.

Comment: @Haresh you mean my answer.

Comment: @AvinashRaj,Yes dear.

Comment: I'm sure about that. `+` wouldn't come after a lookbehind.

Comment: @AvinashRaj,Yes it is possible yet not sure about it but "escape double times" is not solve problem.

Comment: @AvinashRaj,yes but here escape is required for this (" - double quote).

Comment: @AndosBerry,can you please add one more escape before \r and \n and then let me know ?

Answer (score 0):

[Avinash Raj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3297613/avinash-raj) pointed to the most important mistake: the `+` multiplier after positive lookbehind expression.

Using nested marking groups is another mistake. The outer parentheses are useless here and should be removed to reduce complexity.

And backslashes in strings must be escaped with backslashes. As I think that `\r` and `\n` should be passed to the regular expression engine and not the characters with code value 13 and 10, the string to use is

```
"(?<==)(\"[^\"]+\"|[^,=+<>#;\\r\\n]+)"
```